# PL/SQL Developer won't run read queries against read-only linked database

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I just installed PL/SQL Developer (version 10.0.5.1710), and my second query is:

```
SELECT * FROM MySchema.MyTable@DBRead
```

This is kicked back with:

```
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access
ORA-02063: preceding line from DBRead
```

The database is indeed read-only, and that's fine; I rarely need to update anything in this system.

What do I need to adjust in PL/SQL Developer to get it to recognize that I am just trying to read?

The same query, with the same connection info, runs fine in SQL Developer or TOAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume PL/SQL developer runs in the background `SELECT * ... FOR UPDATE;` to make your grid editable. Probably you need to to remove some tick in preferences related to "editing in the grid" or "locking fetched rows". Try to untick preferences->connection->allow edit database source